# How to configure Daeja virtual viewer in my web application with Tomcat 9

Tags: installation, view, tomcat9

I'm trying to set up IBM Daeja's virtual viewer in my web application, but I can't find any step by step or anything similar to tackle the task. Could you give me a hand to carry out this task? the only source of information I found is the following:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/daeja-viewone/5.0.7?topic=modules-configuring-deploying-daeja-viewone-virtual-viewer

I have the sources of Daeja, they are the following

[image]

Any help is welcome, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot you shared, it looks like you are using a very old version of Daeja when applet was ruling in browsers. (Typically it is Daeja Professional Viewer which is out of support by now)

You should use latest viewer version (IBM Daeja ViewONE 5.0.13 as of now) where you can configure Virtual viewer (HTML5)

I hope the following documentation will help you to setup IBM Daeja virtual viewer

https://community.ibm.com/community/user/automation/blogs/dhananjay-bhandarkar/2021/06/11/viewone-configuration